# Copy images and then Delete files that don't exist in another directory with different extension

Tags: script

I'm actually looking for 2 separate scripts for Windows 10. The first one would copy image/video files from an external memory card to 3 separate directories, call them c:\jpegs, d:\cr2s and e:\movies, with JPGs copied to the jpegs directory, raw files (cr2s on my camera) to the cr2s directory, and MOVs to the movies directory. I'd like to have the files put into a subdirectory based on the creation date in YYYYMMDD format.

I would then rename the directories to something more descriptive, i.e., 20180716 - Disney, with the names/structures of the JPG and CR2 subdirectories being (hopefully) consistent. I'd then go through the JPGs, deleting ones that I don't want. I'd then like a second,separate script that would then go through CR2 subdirectories and compare them to the JPG directory, deleting any CR2 file that doesn't have a matching JPG any longer. Just in case I didn't exactly match the subdirectory name, I'd like it to skip any CR2 subdirectory that it cannot find a matching JPG subdirectory, preferably with a warning that it couldn't be found.

Wish this were something I could do on my own. On my to-do list of things to teach myself...

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I was familiar to a degree with the predecessor, XCopy. In looking through the documentation on Robocopy, while it seems powerful, I don't see a way to get file creation dates and use that to determine a directory to sort files into. I did come across a PowerShell script that looks like it will do part 1 at [link](https://ardalis.com/copy-pictures-to-folders-by-date-taken-with-powershell). I haven't tried it yet, but that solves half my questoin (presuming it works).